# Does a Rogue using one handed fire arm and Flick of the Wrist feat allow him to use his Sneak Attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, feats, sneak-attack

Does a Rogue using one handed fire arm and the Flick of the Wrist feat (*Races of the Wild*, p. 150-151) allow him to use his Sneak Attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.

The Flick of the Wrist feat (*Races of the Wild*, p. 150-151) says:

> If you draw a light weapon and make a **melee attack with it** in the same round, you catch your opponent flat-footed (**for the purpose of this attack only**). You can use this feat only once per round and once per opponent during any single combat encounter.

Only a melee attack qualifies for the flat-footed attack from flick of the wrist, and shooting a firearm is a ranged attack.